# In the light of the nature of the allegations

Tags: expressions

I found the phrase 'In the light of the nature of the allegations' in a BBC news  article titled 'Jeff Bezos: Amazon boss accuses National Enquirer of blackmail'.

The context is:

> "American Media believes fervently that it acted lawfully in the reporting of the story of Mr Bezos. Further, at the time of the recent allegations made by Mr Bezos, it was in good faith negotiations to resolve all matters with him," the company said in a statement.
>
> "Nonetheless, ***in light of the nature of the allegations*** published by Mr Bezos, the Board has convened and determined that it should promptly and thoroughly investigate the claims. Upon completion of that investigation, the Board will take whatever appropriate action is necessary."

I don't understand exactly the meaning of 'the nature of the allegations'. Does it mean 'the intention of allegations'? Do they mean the fact that they were in a good relationship but Mr Bezos broke that by the allegations?

Comment: The quote says "in light of", which is the usual expression. The current title of this question has an extraneous "the".

Comment: @sumelic There is a difference between the British and US usage. The OP's quotes show this as the BBC quote says "in the light of" and the American Media quote says "in light of"

Comment: @BoldBen: Oh, interesting! I hadn't realized that.

Comment: @BoldBen: However, I don't see where BBC used "in the light of" in this particular circumstance?

Comment: @sumelic The first line of the post?

Comment: @BoldBen: This question says that, but it doesn't actually seem to be in [the version of the BBC article that I found online](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-47166938)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "the *nature* of X" (a very common collocation) refers to  essential or core characteristics or features of X.  So we can only assume that  the person making that statement is saying that those allegations are *of a kind* that demands prompt and thorough investigation.

American Media publishes a tabloid with stories about Big Foot (Yeti) and space aliens and the marriage difficulties of celebrities and uses "Photoshopped" photographs, whereas Bezos owns the Washington Post, a respected newspaper.

https://www.msnbc.com/the-last-word/watch/jeff-bezos-accuses-national-enquirer-owner-of-blackmail-1439275587549

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into the referenced story yet, but without context, I'm inclined to interpret "the nature of the allegations" as referring to the nature of whatever things are being alleged. For example, allegations of criminal activity are more serious than allegations of impoliteness.

Answer (score 0):

The full article:  [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-02-08/bezos-s-bombshell-puts-enquirer-allegiances-back-in-spotlight)

**in light of**  [TFD idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+light+of)

> Considering (something); given (something. Typically refers to a **new
>   revelation or piece of information** that affects some situation.

As in:

> In the light of the new information involving the magazines ownership
>   and its relationship to being a 'friend' of Trump ( the nature) ...